# How can pass an img url from the constructor to a function and then create/append the image?

Tags: javascript

I have a Card class that takes a url as a parameter, along with several others. The createCard function creates a card based on the parameters. How can I create and append the image(s) within the card based on the url input?

Update: Reworked the code and got the correct result. How can I refine this to be the most efficient?

```
<section id="shootout" class="memory-game">
</section>
```

```js
const game = document.getElementById('shootout')

class Card {
  constructor(name, imgUrl, health, ammo) {
    this.name = name
    this.health = health
    this.ammo = ammo
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl
  }
  createCard(imgUrl) {
    let card = document.createElement('div')
    card.className = this.name
    card.dataset.health = this.health
    card.dataset.ammo = this.ammo
    const addImages = () => {
      let frontFace = new Image()
      frontFace.src = this.imgUrl
      frontFace.className = 'front-face'
      let backFace = new Image()
      backFace.src = 'img/card-back.svg'
      backFace.className = 'back-face'
      card.append(backFace)
      card.append(frontFace)
    }
    addImages()
    game.appendChild(card)
  }
}

// Test Card Instance
const testCard = new Card('ammunition', 'img/react.svg', 1, null).createCard()
```

Updated Code:

```
class Card {
  constructor(name, imgUrl, health, ammo) {
    this.name = name
    this.health = health
    this.ammo = ammo
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl
    this.addImages = (card) => {
      let frontFace = new Image()
      frontFace.src = this.imgUrl
      frontFace.className = 'front-face'
      let backFace = new Image()
      backFace.src = 'img/card-back.svg'
      backFace.className = 'back-face'
      card.append(backFace)
      card.append(frontFace)
    }
  }
  createCard(imgUrl) {
    let card = document.createElement('div')
    card.className = this.name
    card.dataset.health = this.health
    card.dataset.ammo = this.ammo
    this.addImages(card)
    game.appendChild(card)
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `this.imgUrl` to be used in `this.getImages()`?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. I reworked it and posted the new code. Do you think th addImages function is in the best spot now or would it be better to have it where it was before? I had to move it becasue I could not figure out how to pass the card variable back up to the constructor if that makes sense.

Comment: As you have updated the code, and I cannot be bothered to look at the diff, I cannot tell. But, I am intrigued why you have `addImages` as an arrow function and not a method of class `Card`? Anyway, since you code is now working, if you want suggestions for improvement, it is better to post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I could not figure out how to pass the card variable back to addImages method. I finally figured it out though. I have updated the code. Is there a way to add code for comparison or do I just paste the updated code in with the original post?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get achieve the desired result by passing the card variable back up to the addImages method in the Card class constructor.

```
class Card {
  constructor(name, imgUrl, health, ammo) {
    this.name = name
    this.health = health
    this.ammo = ammo
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl
    this.addImages = (card) => {
      let frontFace = new Image()
      frontFace.src = this.imgUrl
      frontFace.className = 'front-face'
      let backFace = new Image()
      backFace.src = 'img/card-back.svg'
      backFace.className = 'back-face'
      card.append(backFace)
      card.append(frontFace)
    }
  }
  createCard(imgUrl) {
    let card = document.createElement('div')
    card.className = this.name
    card.dataset.health = this.health
    card.dataset.ammo = this.ammo
    this.addImages(card)
    game.appendChild(card)
  }
}
```